# SQL Issue using SUBSTRING and LEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, special-characters

```
SELECT [Code], [Due Date Calculation],

--original string that is causing the error
--SUBSTRING([Due Date Calculation], 1, LEN([Due Date Calculation]) - 1) as OG,

--here are the tests that run fine by themselves
LEN([Due Date Calculation]) - 1 as Test1,
SUBSTRING([Due Date Calculation], 1, 2) AS Test2, 
SUBSTRING([Due Date Calculation], 1, LEN([Due Date Calculation])) AS Test3 

FROM [TEST]
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> ***Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.***

I know it has something to do with the way SQL is rendering the data. The data displays a small upside down 'L' when I query it using SQL, but it simply shows a 'D' in the front end. I don't have a good enough reputation to include the images. An example of a typical Codes are `30D`, `60D`, `120D`, `365D`, etc.

I need to drop the trailing D and display what is left.

Thanks for the help.

Here are the results from the SQL Query:
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1cL-bzbZ4IzU2ctYlRNZnJhZjg/view?usp=sharing][1]

Comment: Test this  select min(len([Due Date Calculation]))

Comment: @Blam - sorry this does not work as I am not grouping the output.

Comment: Yes it should select min(len([Due Date Calculation]))  from [TEST]

Comment: watch out for NULL value columns!!!

Comment: @Blam Here is the error I get: 'Due Date Calculation' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: That should work.  Are you sure you have nothing else in the select?

Comment: ...and this my folks is why you never combine multiple pieces of data into a single database column! Isn't it fun splitting them apart! This would be trivial if each portion of this was in its own column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cut off the last character, just do it like this.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = '123D'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,0,LEN(@String))
```

Or if you have multiple characters at the end, then try this which will grab until the numbers stop.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = '123D'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,0,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@String))
```

Both have same results:

```
123
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem correctly you are looking for this

```
Select SUBSTRING([Due Date Calculation],0,CHARINDEX('D',[Due Date Calculation])) 
As [Due Date Calculation]  FROM Test
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17fbf/2)

Comment: 'D' isn't the actual value so this isn't returning any results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample

```
declare @tbl table
(
    c1 nvarchar(9)
)
insert into @tbl values ('30D')
insert into @tbl values ('120D')
insert into @tbl values ('365D')

select  IIF(RIGHT(c1, 1) = 'D', LEFT(C1, LEN(C1)-1), C1)
from    @tbl
```

**Result**
30
120
365

Comment: My data isn't really a 'D' as you can see from my results that I just attached  above.